# Does a brick wall damaged by a plumbing leak need repair?

Tags: kitchens, leak, brick

Recently I discovered a leak in my kitchen.

It turned out to be a small leak, a pipe into the boiler had eroded its solder on the turn, which was an easy fix by the plumber.

The issue is it seems the leak has gone unnoticed for some time and destroyed all the plaster in the area (under kitchen counter behind washing machine). I have cleared away all the fallen and broken plaster but I can see some brick work has been uncovered.

The kitchen is very old 15+ years and needs a full renovation but I am not in a position to do that right now. I am hoping now the leak is fixed and the area dried out it is a matter of leaving it till the kitchen remodeling years from now.

Based on the pictures below is the wall ok to leave as is or is there any immediate actions I should take to avoid further deterioration ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming the water wasn't freezing and causing micro-cracks then that brick's lifespan has been reduced by 2 years out of 300.

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, brick (unlike wood) does not rot when wet.

Should be fine to leave it until you do the whole place over.

*Technically,* I'd say the *plaster* was damaged and the brick wall looks just fine, from what I can see. Plaster being basically cosmetic is an "optional" part of the wall.

Comment: And bricks get wet all time when they're used on the outside of a house.

Comment: The right copper tube where it makes a left with  a 90 has a small leak. With the damage you did to the bricks you probably only have a few hundred years left before they fail if the others hold up.